# MongoDb, Cloning database error: illegal argument combination: cannot specify --db and --uri

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, mern

I am trying to duplicate a database called `database_A` in the same cluster.
The result should be a new database called `database_B` with the exact same data.

I am trying to follow the instructions [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongodump/#copy-clone-a-database).

It explains how to do this locally:

1. Use mongodump to dump the test database to an archive mongodump-test-db:

> mongodump --archive="mongodump-test-db" --db=test

2. Use mongorestore with --nsFrom and --nsTo to restore (with database name change) from the archive:

> mongorestore --archive="mongodump-test-db" --nsFrom='test.*'
> --nsTo='examples.*'

In order to achieve the same result in the cluster, it says:

> Include additional options as necessary, such as to specify the uri or
> host, username, password and authentication database.

However, when I try to add the `uri` to achieve the first step:

```
mongodump --uri mongodb+srv://hihi:password@cluster0.fklgt.mongodb.net --archive="mongodump-test-db" --db=test_db
```

I get this error:

```
illegal argument combination: cannot specify --db and --uri
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add db in URI- like connection `uri/[db]`

> mongodb+srv://hihi:password@cluster0.fklgt.mongodb.net/test_db

---

```
mongodump --uri mongodb+srv://hihi:password@cluster0.fklgt.mongodb.net/test_db --archive="mongodump-test-db"
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption-mongodump-uri

> /database Optional. The name of the database to authenticate if the connection string includes authentication credentials in the form of username:password@. If /database is not specified and the connection string includes credentials, the driver will authenticate to the admin database. See also authSource.

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/connection-string/